# I cannot use a method "whereNotIn()" using Firestore android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

[Firestore documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8RBE.png)

[My app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paDC8.png)

I have no option to query my data by using method "whereNotIn()"

Comment: What is the version of your Cloud Firestore SDK?

Comment: com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.3

Comment: I updated sdk and now its working thank for help

Answer (score 1):

Update your Firestore SDK to 21.7.0

`Query.whereNotIn()` was  [added in v21.7.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#firestore_v21-7-0)